# Event dispatch when save order in Magento Admin panel

Tags: magento, backend

i try to catch an order when it created in the admin panel of Magento, i try the next event: 
controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_save
but this method made a $this->_getSession()->clear(); and delete the data of my order.
what event should i catch? 
any ideas, thanks

Comment: check below link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92360/magento-2-category-list-query/97696 Hope this'll help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with any of the following events:-

- `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data` (in file "`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php`" of line - 245)
- `sales_order_place_before` (in file "`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`" of line - 1072)

Both of them has been referenced for Magento v1.6.0.0.

However, I tried searching for the event mentioned "`controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_save`", but I didn't get any in this Magento version of 1.6.0.0 & 1.5.1.0.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data dispatch in any modification of the order, for example, when i select the customer in the create order process in the admin, as o can discriminate in the diferents dispatch?? if(".....")